# Magento 2 How can I change product name for category page only

Tags: magento2

I want to replace all Product name with one Product Attribute in Category page only. Any idea how can I achieve it? Any suggestion or guidance? No need to provide code.

Comment: Want to changes view on category page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To achieve your need to some code at template file phtml**

- First, you need to enable your attribute for product list from admin. Navigate to the `Stores>Attributes>Product` and search your attribute., Then go to  `Storefront Properties` tab find  `Used in Product Listing` and me it's value to**YES**. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/attributes-product.html

**Do the indexing from admin and flush for apply changes.**

Then open **`list.phtml`** from `app/design/{ThemeVendor}/{Themename}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product`,Then  and 
find the code:

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

and  add your attribute value using

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getData('{YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE}'), '{YOUR_ATTRIBUTE_CODE}') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I almost forgot this, I was thinking too much about by creating the module for this.. and forgot that I can directly do this via template file.

Comment: don't need any extension. But It is always developer  call how they manage their  requirement .

Comment: yes that's true.